# Why is it called Truck Attack?

Tags: technique, brazilian-jiu-jitsu, terminology, attack

Why is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51O_f1QKuyg) attack called Truck Attack/Position in BJJ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a quote in [this post](https://www.10thplanetjj.com/threads/23551-Why-do-you-call-the-position-The-Truck?s=b5d72f662176269769c196413582b4fe&p=272883&viewfull=1#post272883):

> "Suddenly there were all these roads you could take, which is the reason I ended up calling the position the truck." Master also says he spent a great deal of time in the producer's truck while working for the UFC, where tons of options and split second decisions are made, just like in the truck. "It's just like trying to orchestrate a UFC pay-per-view - unless you understand how to put it all together, it's going to come out looking like shit."

Comment: Frustratingly, that's the only place I've found that quote.

Comment: [Messaged Eddie](https://twitter.com/FuzzyDugganSC/status/1514243400014385159?t=xopQKNKj4XYb_YFylXb4lA&s=19) to see if he'll settle it.